# How to require dotenv/config file on (before) PM2 starts

Tags: node.js, pm2

I run node app like this:

```
node -r dotenv/config dist/app
```

I need something similar using PM2:

```
pm2 start -r dotenv/config dist/app.js --name appname // doesn't work
```

I receive the next error: `error: unknown option -r`

Comment: chekout https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
you can load the .env files from the script itself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [node_args](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#general).

```sh
pm2 start --node-args="-r dotenv/config" dist/app.js --name appname
```

Comment: This! Finally. Working on ubuntu 20 / node 10 / pm2 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Shell script:

```
// pm2-start.sh

NODE_ENV=production &&
node -r dotenv/config dist/app
```

Then I ran `pm2 start pm2-start.sh --name appname`

Tip I have also ran: `pm2 startup` then copied command that pm2 instructed to run in order to activate the auto startup of all apps that are registered via pm2.

Then I ran `pm2 save` to save the auto service.

Note: pm2 lists apps distinctly between server account respectively. That means that apps that are listed on user A will not be listed on user B. That's true for the `pm2 startup` command - that should be done for each account.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me because I was using an ecosystem file AND cluster mode which behaves really odd (not like without cluster mode...).

I installed dotenv as dev dependency at the root (I was using yarn workspaces too).

Then I did this:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'path/to/your/.env' })

module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'app',
            script: 'server/dist/index.js',
            instances: 2,
            exec_mode: 'cluster',
            instance_var: 'APP_INSTANCE_SEQ',
            // listen_timeout: 10000,
            // restart_delay: 10000,
        }
    ]
}
```