# Load ENV vars with dotenv before node-config

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, dotenv, node-config

I want to load environment variables into the general `config` of my Express app. Locally I work with a `.env` file, but when deploying, I'll inject the env vars into the docker container.

So, I've got a `default.json` with some hard-coded config values. Then I've got the `custom-environment-variables.json` file like so:

```
  "app": {
    "nodeEnv": "NODE_ENV",
    "port": "PORT",
    "hostname": "HOSTNAME"
  }
  "mongoDb": {
    "connectionString": "MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING"
  },
  "redis": {
    "connectionString": "REDIS_CONNECTION_STRING"
  },
  "logDna": {
    "key": "LOGDNA_KEY"
  }
```

and a `.env` file within the root dir of my project.

In server initiating file I've got:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import * as config from 'config';

console.log(process.env);
console.log(config);
```

I also tried placing them in a normal order:

```
import * as config from 'config';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();
```

Another thing I tried is to separate the app declaration from the services init and app start. Like so in `app.ts`:

```
import * as App from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env);

const app = new App();
export app;
```

And then in `index.ts`:

```
import app from './app';
import * as config from 'config';

console.log(config);

// app.use() and other inits
app.listen(...);
```

But to no avail. The `.env` file is loaded, I can see the vars in `process.env`, but they do not get loaded by the `config` in `custom-environment-variables.json`. F.e. the `nodeEnv`, `port` and `hostname` variables are loaded. But they are loaded into the container before the application is started.

This brings me to the thought that the `config` loads before the `dotenv` module manages to load the values from the `.env` file. Essentially, it seems like the problem will only be existent in DEV env, since it's the only place I'll be loading environment variables from `.env` file. For any other environment, they'll be present in the container environment before the app even starts.

Can I maybe force re-load `config`?

Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: *`dotenv`* will only expose those variables on `process.env` and will not inject them onto other modules irrespective of the order. Ideally `dotenv.config();` should be as soon as the app starts. What do you want to achieve from `config` module (but they do not get loaded by the config in custom-environment-variables.json) ..what does `config` do

Comment: @ambianBeing [config env vars](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Environment-Variables#custom-environment-variables)
Basically, it finds environment variables with the same name as the ones I've declared in my config files and loads their values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I settled for external loading of the local env vars, alongside the node process startup:

`node --require=dotenv/config src/index.js`

inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56833072/1430394).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Typescript then you should open the file that is the entry point for the app, create a new file where the `dotenv` commands are ran at the top level, not inside any function, and import it to the main file.

Example:

```
// index.ts

import './load-env';

// Rest of your imports & code...
```

```
// load-env.ts

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config(); // Runs before any const declarations in any other file
```

If your editor keeps reordering your imports, you can rename the load-env file into something that is higher alphabetically, such as `a-load-env.ts`.